# What Inkscape toolbar icons are these?

Tags: inkscape

I watched a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3_BrJlntX0) and noted that the icons in the toolbars are different from the default icons that come with Inkscape:

Left: Traditional | Right: From Video

[image][image][image][image]

I wonder what these icons are.

Comment: Why don't you ask the video poster? It's probably a custom theme, probably running on a Linux distro.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Customizing_Inkscape): *Icons are all in an icons.svg file located in <Inkscape install directory>/share/icons/*. Basing on your screenshot, you can find the icon theme [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1168331/).

Comment: Awesome - That did the trick!  Just download and place icons.svg in ~/config/inkscape/icons

Comment: I will post the comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Inkscape [documentation](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Customizing_Inkscape):

> Icons are all in an icons.svg file located in *<Inkscape install
>   directory>/share/icons/*.
>
> Alternatively, a custom icons/icons.svg file can be loaded from the
>   *user Inkscape preferences directory*.

Basing on your screenshot, you can find the icon theme on [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1168331/).

[image: gnome-look.org icons]